# Mysql compare ip address

Tags: mysql, ip-address

I have a database which stores IP address with its location. I only store the first 3 network ID of IP address in the table.

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
|ip_address(varchar)|location(varchar)|
+-------------------+-----------------+
| 1.2.3             |       A         |
| 1.2.4             |       A         |
| 1.22.33           |       B         |
| 1.100.99          |       C         |
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Let say my IP is 1.2.3.4 or others 1.100.99.20, how do I compare the IP with the table to get the location?

Comment: Did you make up those addresses?  It almost looks like /23. which could be solved with some boolean masking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work and be indexable too:

```
SELECT location
FROM WhateverTable
WHERE ip_address = SUBSTRING_INDEX(?, '.', 3)
```

Where you supply the value '1.100.99.20' for the `?` parameter.

---

You should be aware that the IP addresses you store are misleading. The official IP address format permits shortened strings, but not the way you probably think. For example:

```
mysql> select inet_ntoa(inet_aton('1.100.99'));
+----------------------------------+
| inet_ntoa(inet_aton('1.100.99')) |
+----------------------------------+
| 1.100.0.99                       |
+----------------------------------+
```

I bet you would expect it to return 1.100.99.0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer..the IP above I just type it randomly..dont mind that.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT location
FROM address_table
WHERE AND INET_ATON(@my_address) BETWEEN INET_ATON(CONCAT(ip_address, '.0'))
                                     AND INET_ATON(CONCAT(ip_address, '.255'))
```

Of course this query cannot use the index even if it exists...

---

I recommend you do NOT trim the ip_address column value. And the best way is to store not trimmed subnet address but IP addresses range (from - till) in two columns in numeric form - this protects against typos (and decreases rows amount). You may use generated columns with string representation of IP addresses ranges if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most pragmatic approach, but it does the work.

We could use the `LOCATE()` function, which takes two arguments representing the substring that you’re looking for and the string in which to look for it. (locate function reference: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s06.html)

The first argument that is going to be passed is the column `ip_address` and the second argument will be your IP (e.g: 1.2.3.4).

```
SELECT location
FROM that_table
WHERE LOCATE(ip_address, 'the_ip') >= 1;
```

If we get the number greater or equal than one, it means that it found a match, therefore that ip is going to have a location.

Comment: You are leaving out an important detail.  If he compares to the IP address, there will be no match.  OP stated that the table only contains the 1st 3 octets.  Your answer should reflect a way of stripping the final octet off the ip address.

Comment: Changed the answer, didn't notice that detail. 
It should work now.

Comment: Thank you..it works. I never tried locate() function before.